# "TypeError: url_1.URL is not a constructor" with NPM's twitter-v2

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, twitter

I am currently working on a Twitter bot. I am trying right now to post a Tweet with my account set-up to work with [Twitter API v2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api), using NPM's [twitter-v2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-v2) with Webpack 5.74.0 and the latest verison of NodeJS.
To get `twitter-v2` to work, I installed NPM's [node-polyfill-webpack-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin), since it looks like it's a pretty old code made for Webpack <5, and it didn't work without. I am also using Webpack's `serve` to test the bot

Here is my testing code using `twitter-v2` :

```
const Twitter = require('twitter-v2')
//or import {Twitter} from 'twitter-v2' ?

        ...

const client = new Twitter({
        consumer_key: [My API Key],
        consumer_secret: [My API Key Secret],
        access_token_key: [My Access Token],
        access_token_secret: [My Access Token Secret]
})
const params = {
        text:"test"
}
const urlParams = {}

const {data} = await client.post('tweets',params,urlParams)
console.log(data)
```

From what I understood, from the `twitter-v2` doc and the [Twitter API's POST doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/post-tweets), with `client.post(path, body, urlParams)` :

- `path` is the API's endpoint (here 'tweets')
- `body` are the *JSON body parameters* (here since I just want to tweet "test", is `{text:"test"}`, or `{"text":"test"}` ?)
- `urlParams` are the parameters in the URL after the endpoint, however I don't think it's right since *POST /2/tweets* doesn't need this, it's more *[DELETE /2/tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/manage-tweets/api-reference/delete-tweets-id)* that would need one (the `/id:` parameter)

However when I launch the local server (with `webpack serve --open --config [My config file]`), the following error shows in the console :

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: url_1.URL is not a constructor                     twitter.js:50
```

It comes from the following lines in the package :

```
const url_1 = require("url");

        ...

async post(endpoint, body, parameters) {
        const url = new url_1.URL(`https://api.twitter.com/2/${endpoint}`);
        ...
}
```

I don't know how to fix this error, I didn't find anything much on the Internet.
From what I read, `const url = new url_1.URL(..)` is an old way to do things and it's maybe why it can't work. Is there a way to fix it without touching the package's source code, or should I ditch it and doing my Authentifications manually (which I don't understand much) ?
Thanks for helping.

Comment: Mmm, unfortunately that npm package has not been updated for a couple of years, so I'm not quite sure. There are some more recent Node packages available for v2, including a Twitter SDK. https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twitter-v2` is deprecated, [Twitter SDK](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/sdks/overview) is a much better alternative. Thanks [Andy Piper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/262478/andy-piper) for pointing this out.